PyScript <script type="py-editor"> Error Unable to use SharedArrayBuffer due insecure environment
I'm using PyScript to run a simple Python script in my HTML file to display a pandas DataFrame. However, after loading the page in browser and clicking the run button of the code block I'm encountering an error related to SharedArrayBuffer due to an insecure environment.
If I run any code directly from  it works perfectly. Its Only when I try to run the code from the code block it throws me an error.
Environment:

Running the application locally using VSCode Live Server.

PyScript version: 2024.6.2

Python library: pandas


Steps to Reproduce:

Create an HTML file with the below code.

Open the HTML file.

run the py-editor code block

Observe the error in the browser console.


Question:
How can I resolve this SharedArrayBuffer issue when running PyScript? image of the error
Below is my HTML code:
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.6.2/core.css">
        <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.6.2/core.js"></script>

        <style>
            #loading { outline: none; border: none; background: transparent }
        </style>

        <script type="module">
            const loading = document.getElementById('loading');
            addEventListener('py:ready', () => loading.close());
            loading.showModal();
        </script>
        
        <py-config>
            packages = ["pandas"]
        </py-config>
    </head>

    <body>
        <dialog id="loading">
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        </dialog>

        <script type="py-editor">df</script>

        <script type="py">
            import pandas as pd
            data = {
                'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
                'Age': [25, 30, 35],
                'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
            }
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        </script>

    </body>
</html>

UPDATE
So I made some progress. I used the mini-coi script and was able to run the code from the py-editor (AKA py-REPL) without the SharedArrayBuffer error but now it's not able to access the data frame that I created using the script type="py".
This is the error:
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python312.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 574, in eval_code_async
await CodeRunner(
File "/lib/python312.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 394, in run_async
coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 1, in
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

did you run it in other web browser? Maybe it is only problem with web browser.

The code block doesn't get executed.
Yes i tried in Chrome, edge and firefox. All give me the same error.
If i use older version of PyScript with the same code it works perfectly.

maybe you should send it to authors of PyScript as issue

I checked PyScript SharedArrayBuffer in Google and I found that PyScript has  information about this problem in FAQ as one of the first points :) https://docs.pyscript.net/2024.6.2/faq/

if you tried in other browser and used older version then you should describe it in question (not in comments).

Alright, so I went through the common problem page on the website and seems something to do with security so I setup https(with self signed certificate - local server) but still it give me the same error.

security doesn't have to means https but some parameters in request headers. But if FAQ can't help then maybe checked PyScript SharedArrayBuffer in Google to find other places. And if it will not help then you may send issue to authors.

Thanks for your help. If you still find anything let me know.

"What are you hoping to achieve with it?"
I want to be able to execute code from the browser directly from my html page. In my sample HTML page, I create a data frame in the 
You can have multiple Py-editors in html page but not type = "py" and type = "Py-editor" together in one html page.To perform dataframe operation using Py-editor use the following code.
https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/long-silence/latest/

Thank you. In the older version of pyscript, I could use  and  together. for example have my data frame created using the (now 
Apology for giving the wrong information. Yes  is  now but both  and 
Sure! Here is the code.
https://leoalps.pyscriptapps.com/pyscript/

in the new version of Pyscript, I'm unable to print a Matplotlib graph using the py-editor.
The error i get:
pyodide.ffi.JsException: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of object '#'

refer https://thefun.pyscriptapps.com/icy-heart/latest/ for the Matplotlib graph using py-editor.

Both 
In the example provided at thefun.pyscriptapps.com/icy-heart/latest, the graph is rendered inside a . However, in my case, I prefer to have the graph output displayed directly within the 
You can use mine one. If possible help me with the python syntax highlighting part. https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/matplot/latest/

I noticed that your code isn't displaying the graph directly within the 
As of what I know it was not possible to render this way. Not sure if there is any latest update @Jeff Glass will update you with it.

it was possible in version 2023.05.1. you can check this sample that i have made
https://leoalps.pyscriptapps.com/pyscript-2023-05-1/
